# Firebase Cloud Messaging Error : Couldn't resolve host 'fcm.googleapis.com'

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

We use firebase and haven't had any problems. But now when I try to send a notification with our server we get this error:

```
Problem occurred: Couldn't resolve host 'fcm.googleapis.com'
```

This is my code :

```
define("FIREBASE_API_KEY", "MY_API_KEY");
define("FIREBASE_FCM_URL", "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
```

We can send notifications through Google firebase but not on our server. Our server is located in iran.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a lawyer nor an expert on this subject, nor is this legal or professional advice. I am also not officially speaking for Google.

It is entirely possible that your server's ISP, the government of Iran, or Google/the FCM team has blocked the usage of FCM. I would try on a server located outside of Iran and see if it works there.

Comment: Step 1 is identifying what the problem is (who is unable to resolve this, why they can't resolve it). Depending on what that is, step 2 will vary (you may have to switch ISPs, move your server, etc.). As a first step, I would try accessing FCM from a non-Iranian server and see if it works.